# Datetime conversion giving error

Tags: c#

consider me a beginner in c# 
I am doing some changes  in a pre developed software (C#.Net) , we are saving data by datewise , Currently in insert query (build in c#) we are passing GETDATE() to save today date , but now we have to save data on the basis of a different date.
When I am building query in c# , I m passing that a datetime variable into query
after conversion , conversion as follow

```
Date_Stamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-IN"));
```

but it is showing error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

The reason to convert is coz these date field are getting displayed in format 
`ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));`

Which will give 2017-07-13 14:56:30.233 as 13-jul-2017 on front end (as per requirement). We cant change this part of code as it is being used in lot of places , hard to change .

Problem is 
variable storing value as

```
2017-12-07 00:00:00.000
```

which give after conversion 07-Dec-2017 [wrong - it is needed as 12-jul-2017]

GETDATE storing value as

`2017-07-12 14:56:30.233`

which is after conversion coming right as 12-jul-2017

I know there is no datetime format in sql server when it come to storing data

But can we store value from variable [2017-12-07 ] as [2017-07-12 ] ?
How GETDATE() give us date in year-month-date format 
?

Comment: `DateTime` has NO format. It's a binary value. The same applies to SQL Server - `GETDATE()` has no format. It's a `datetime` value. Formats apply only when you convert it to a string or try to parse it from a string. The same date will appear differently if you use a different culture

Comment: Why are you converting the value to a *string* in the first place? Just cast it to a DateTime : `(DateTime)dt.Rows[0][0]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did not I mention that myself in question , I am seeking solution here

Comment: You did : `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()`. Why are you doing this? Most likely the value is a `DateTime` already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that conversion is because ParseExact method need first parameter as string , not DateTime

Comment: You don't need to parse a `DateTime` into a `DateTime`. What is the query and what is the *actual* type of the field's value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , if used (DateTime)dt.Rows[0][0] than it will convert for sure but when execute query with this converted value it will show  - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: `varchar` ? Why would `GETDATE()` or a date value be converted to a `VARCHAR` ? What is the query? Also, how are dates stored in the database? Using `varchar` to store dates is a serious bug

Comment: Post your SQL query and the table schema. It's impossible to understand what the problem is without the relevant code. Either the query returns a `datetime` and you don't need any conversions anywhere, or there is a bug and date data are either stored or retrieved using the wrong type

Answer (score 2):

Neither .NET's nor SQL Server's date related type have *any* format. All of them are binary values, just like integers and decimals. Formats apply only when they are explicitly or implicitly converted to strings, or parsed from strings.

Assuming your query looked something like `SELECT GETDATE(), ...` and you loaded the results to an DataTable, the values will be returned as `DateTime` values. If you used a strongly-typed DataTable you could just use the value. With a generic `DataTable` the value will be boxed and return as an object.

All you have to do is just cast the field value to `DateTime` :

```
Date_Stamp = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0][0];
```

This will also work for `date` and `datetime2` types. `datetimeoffset` is returned as `DateTimeOffset`. `time` is returned as `TimeSpan`.

The problem in the original is caused because the field value is formatted into a string using the current culture `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()` first. Then ParseExact is called trying to parse it using a *different* format. A simple `DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())` would have worked (even though it would be wasteful), since both `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ToString()` use the same culture.

**UPDATE**

Reading date fields from a table has no issues - the values are returned using the appropriate date type. For example, running `SELECT StartDate from ThatTable` will return `DateTime` if the table's schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE ThatTable
(
    ID int,
    StartDate datetime
)
```

Problems are caused if, instead of using the correct type, dates are stored as strings in VARCHAR columns. That's a serious bug that needs to be fixed. There is *NO* assurance that the strings can be parsed to dates at all, or that they follow the same format. It's all too easy for some faulty application code to use eg `DateTime.Now.ToString()` and store a *localized* string in there.

Even if the format is the same, it's just wasteful and unreliable. The string takes more storage than the equivalent type, introduces conversion issues, *prevents* the use of date functions, and the server can't apply date optimizations to queries and indexing.

Comment: ok , than how the ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") showing two different conversion if date stored in sql server does not have any format

Comment: Neither .NET nor SQL Server have any language-specific format. Nor do MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, DB2. Dates are binary values. If you have to deal with formats, something is wrong. Perhaps you passed a DateTime as a string instead of DateTime. Or a query was created using string concatenation instead of using parameters

Comment: I still don't know what you saying but if I convert  date as Date_Stamp.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") before inserting as parameter than it show date in different format in sql table , same like GETDATE() store as 2017-07-13  which was required , now I don't have to make conversion in so many places

Comment: @ThePerson I won't repeat that `datetime` has no format. You don't have to perform any conversion in any place if you avoid strings. You haven't posted your queries or your table schema so it's impossible to help more. If you have to perform *any* conversion, if you have to make *any* call to `Parse` or `ParseExact` or `CAST()`, you have bugs

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos , all it matter for me the problem resolved , Thanks for your time , Probably you  are sticking to sql part only , need to consider c# part also as per question. Does not matter now . Thanks again